What is the background knowledge for this type of question divisible sequence? How does it work?
QUESTION:
Let $m$ be a positive integer, and let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{4m+2}$ be an arithmetic sequence with non-zero common difference. If removing two terms $a_i$ and $a_j$ ($i < j$) leaves $4m$ terms that can be evenly divided into $m$ groups, and each group of four numbers forms an arithmetic sequence, then call the sequence $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{4m+2}$ a $(i, j)$-divisible sequence.
(I) List all possible pairs $(i, j)$ such that $1 \leq i < j \leq 6$ making the sequence $a_1, a_2, ..., a_6$ a $(i, j)$-divisible sequence.
(II) Prove that when $m \geq 3$, the sequence $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{4m+2}$ is a $(2, 13)$-divisible sequence.
(III) Given any two distinct integers $i$ and $j$ chosen from $1, 2, ..., 4m+2$ with $i < j$, denote by $P_m$ the probability that the sequence $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{4m+2}$ is a $(i, j)$-divisible sequence. Show that $P_m > \frac{1}{8}$.

The content below is a rough idea of how to do it by hand.

The first question is easy; just understand the problem:
(1) i, j = (1, 2), (1, 6), (5, 6)

The second question:
Let $\left\{{a}_{m+2}\right\}$ have a common difference $d$. For the second part, we can start with the simplest case where $m=3$ and remove ${a}_{2},{a}_{13}$ from $\left\{{a}_{14}\right\}$:
[ {a}{1},{a}{3},{a}{4},{a}{5},{a}{6},{a}{7},{a}{8},{a}{9},{a}{10},{a}{11},{a}{12},{a}{14} ]
We try to construct three arithmetic sequences each with four terms. Let's consider the sequence $\left\{{a}_{1},{a}_{{i}_{1}},{a}_{{i}_{2}},{a}_{{i}_{3}}\right\}$ where $i_i\geqslant 3$. The common difference of this sequence should be at least $2d$.
If $d_0=2d,i_1=3,i_2=5,i_3=7$, we will find that the remaining eight terms cannot form two more arithmetic sequences, so let's try $d_0=3d$. It is easy to arrange:$\left\{{a}_{1},{a}_{4},{a}_{7},{a}_{10}\right\}$ $\left\{{a}_{3},{a}_{6},{a}_{9},{a}_{12}\right\}$ $\left\{{a}_{5},{a}_{8},{a}_{11},{a}_{14}\right\}$
For $m\geqslant 4$, as long as we first arrange these three arithmetic sequences, then divide ${a}_{15},{a}_{16},\cdots ,{a}_{4m+2}$ into $\left\{{a}_{{4k}+3},{a}_{{4k}+4},{a}_{{4k}+5},{a}_{{4k}+6}\right\}$ for $3\leqslant k\leqslant m-1$, we're done.

(3) This question is asking about what conditions on $i$ and $j$ make it possible to split $\left\{{a}_{4m+2}\right\}$ into $(i,j)$.
Firstly, let's count the total number of possibilities for $(i,j)$: $C_{4m+2}^2=\frac{(4m+2)(4m+1)}{2}=8m^2+6m+1$
Similarly, we start with the simplest situation where all the resulting sequences have equal differences, which means after removing ${a}_{i},{a}_{j}$ from $\left\{{a}_{4m+2}\right\}$, the remaining elements can be divided into $m$ groups such that each group has four consecutive numbers.
What conditions do $i$ and $j$ need to satisfy? Clearly, $i=1,j=2$ works. We remove ${a}_{1}$ first, then ${a}_{2}$. Then $\left\{{a}_{3},{a}_{4},...,{a}_{4m+2}\right\}$ can be divided into $\left\{{a}_{{4k}+3},{a}_{{4k}+4},{a}_{{4k}+5},{a}_{{4k}+6}\right\}(0\leqslant k\leqslant m-1)$ in order to meet the requirements. Since the sequences are always composed of four elements, both $i=4p+1$ and $j=4q+2$ ($0\leqslant p\leqslant q\leqslant m$) work. How many ways are there to choose $p$ and $q$?
When $p=0$, $q$ has $m+1$ choices. When $p=1$, $q$ has $m$ choices. ... When $p=m$, $q$ has $1$ choice. So there are $\frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}$ ways in total. However, compared to $8m^2+6m+1$, the probability is only greater than $\frac{1}{16}$ but not $\frac{1}{8}$. Therefore, we need to look for other situations.
Note that the premise of question (2) is not in the form of $i = 4p + 1, j = 4q + 2$ $(0 \le p \le q \le m)$, but rather in the form of $i = 4p + 2, j = 4q + 1$ $(0 \le p < q \le m)$.
We also need to note that this form is not always feasible. For example, $j = i + 3$ does not work. Let $m = 1$, then $(i, j) = (2, 5)$, and it's impossible for $a_1, a_3, a_4, a_6$ to be an arithmetic sequence.
What about $j = i + 7$? Let $m = 2$, then $(i, j) = (2, 9)$,
$a_1, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_{10}$ can be divided into $\{a_1, a_3, a_5, a_7\}$ and $\{a_2, a_4, a_6, a_8\}$
When $j = i + 11$, we can construct according to the method in question (2), as long as $(i, j) = (2, 4m + 1)$, we can construct $m$ arithmetic sequences with common difference $m$. At this point, we find that except for $j = i + 3$, other forms of $i = 4p + 2, j = 4q + 1$ $(0 \le p < q \le m)$ are possible. The probability here is actually enough.

